# Correlation stability

Tags: regression, correlation

I have 10 predictors that are significantly correlated with Y for 37 years.

My training period is 80% of 37 years so that makes 30 years and 7 years for validation period.

I noticed that the correlation coefficient of some predictors with Y have these characteristics are positive in 30 years and becomes negative in the last 7 years.

For example, X1 has a correlation of 0.5 in 30 years but it becomes -0.6 in the last years. Is it valid to eliminate these predictors as they may contaminate (or lessen) the validation scores during my validation years?

I feel like I am making wrong assumptions but I don't know what they are.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Removing observations that don't "fit" invalidates the work. It's like lying to yourself because it makes you feel better. I wouldn't suggest it! I will say that I find that people tend to ignore the weaknesses of Pearson's product-moment (which I assume you're using). The rho calculation is **highly** influenced by outliers. Outliers shouldn't be removed either, by the way - that whole lying to yourself thing -- the same applies with outliers for the most part.

Comment: Thanks. This leads me to my question, is there a test that could eliminate these "unstable" correlation beforehand?

Comment: What is the statistical measure of "unstable"? Is it your *perception* of instability? How did you determine it was unstable? Start with the assumptions of Pearson's product-moment correlation coefficient. If the data met the assumptions, then the only other option you have (I think) is a partial correlation for parametric analysis. You always have non-parametric methods, though. For more specific information, you're going to have to define your focus (the problem you're trying to solve, the question you're trying to answer, or the hypothesis you're trying to prove and maybe sample data.)

Comment: After some reading, I think I will need to perform Chow Test to perform regression stability and remove the predictors that have significant structural breaks in the regression model. Thanks for replying to my post.